# Role based authentication, can some please explain these lines

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core Role Based Authentication.
Some one please explain this code. Also correct me if I am wrong.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

services.AddAuthentication(x => {
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x => {
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = false;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the comments in the following code:

```
//AddIdentity(): Configure Asp.net Core Identity uses the custom model Application and implement roles.
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();

//AddAuthentication: Adding Authentication configure the AuthenticationOptions.
services.AddAuthentication(x => {
    // set the default scheme by AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext, String).
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    // set the default scheme by ChallengeAsync(HttpContext, String, AuthenticationProperties).
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    // set the fallback default scheme for all the other defaults.
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
  //AddJwtBearer(): Adding Jwt Bearer and configure it via the JwtBearerOptions.
  .AddJwtBearer(x => {
    //Gets or sets if HTTPS is required for the metadata address or authority. The default is true. This should be disabled only in development environments.
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    //Defines whether the bearer token should be stored in the AuthenticationProperties after a successful authorization.
    x.SaveToken = false;
    //Gets or sets the parameters used to validate identity tokens.
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        //Gets or sets a boolean that controls if validation of the SecurityKey that signed the securityToken is called.
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        //Gets or sets the SecurityKey that is to be used for signature validation.
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
        //Gets or sets a boolean to control if the issuer will be validated during token validation.
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        //Gets or sets a boolean to control if the audience will be validated during token validation.
        ValidateAudience = false,
        //Gets or sets the clock skew to apply when validating a time.
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
```

Reference:

[Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[AuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAuthentication Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.authenticationservicecollectionextensions.addauthentication?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[AuthenticationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[JwtBearerExtensions.AddJwtBearer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.jwtbearerextensions.addjwtbearer?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[JwtBearerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbeareroptions?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[TokenValidationParameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Can you help me understand whether `ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true` is required when either of audience or issuer is set to true?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET core Authentication and Authorization are provided as Middleware you have to configure them in ConfigureServices() and connect the middleware in Configure().

In the above code we are setting up and configuring the JWT Token and adding the required components to ASP.NET's processing pipeline.

Here are some links for the same

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/login-and-role-based-custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core-3-1/